# Is there a MAMP-like application with up-to-date components (Apache, MySQL and PHP)?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, mysql, mamp

I'm using PHP and MySQL to develop websites and web applications on my Mac. Using Git and a deployment service I deploy the code to the production environment. I'm looking for a MAMP-like application that includes up-to-date versions of it's components (Apache, MySQL and PHP).

In the past I've used [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) Pro. Unfortunately they stopped updating the components. (PHP 5.4 was added two weeks ago; that's four months after the official release! And Apache HTTP Server 2.4 is still not available.)

Later on I switched to [WebStart](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/products/webstart/overview/), because it was the only application that included PHP 5.4. Unfortunately they didn't release any updates since, so I'm still stuck on version RC4 of PHP 5.4.

I'm looking for an application that is **currently up-to-date** and that's **very likely to stay up-to-date**. Am I overlooking an option, or is that just not possible?

<sub>If there's an application that includes PostgreSQL and nginx as well, it would be even more awesome. But that might be a bit too much to ask for.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html) has a Mac version that is not too far off up-to-date - they promise a Mac update next
- [MAMPstack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack) is a Bitnami stack

Comment: Both packages are still at PHP 5.3. I'm afraid this is an impossible question, so I'll accept your answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

[AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com/downloads) provides PHP 7.1.8, Apache 2.4.27 and MySQL 5.6.37

Hope you'll enjoy.